# Android Media Codec API basic example

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediacodec

I've recently came across Android Media Codec API and wanted to try out a sample project have gone through the documentation I've understand the flow and I know I have to use media extractor, media encoder and media mixer to clone a video and should apply effects and filters on surfaces however im struggling integrating them and would like to understand them with a very basic snippet or sample? 
I would be great help if you can provide a snipped for cloning a video and also example for using surfaces

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can have a look at the grafika project, it has all the sample codes for mediacodec. https://github.com/google/grafika

And the bigflake is also good reference for mediacodec, it is the cts test code for mediacodec. https://www.bigflake.com/mediacodec/